# Does an AMQPNetLite client connecting to ActiveMQ Artemis via AMQPS require the client to store client certificates?

Tags: .net, ssl, activemq-artemis

I have a .NET Client that needs to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis instances on AWS. I'm able to connect to them over AMQP without enabling SSL/TLS on the load balancer sitting in front of the AWS instances. But I need to enable SSL/TSL connections over AMQPS and my research shows that I would need to create and store certs on my client, apart from the certificates on the Artemis Server (which is a given for SSL/TLS connections).

Here is the link - http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html

I'm trying to understand if there is a way around needing installation and management of certs on the client side since this would be a maintenance hassle. On the server, I intend to use AWS Certificate Manage to take care of cert management, but on the client this would be inconvenient. Any inputs on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who may have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server-side certificate is signed by an authority which is trusted by your JVM then you shouldn't need to import the certificate into your client-side truststore. If you're using self-signed certificates or certificates signed by an untrusted authority then your client *will* need the server's certificate in its truststore.

Each JVM version (e.g. 8, 9, 10, 11) and implementation (e.g. Oracle vs. OpenJDK vs. IBM) for the various supported platforms (e.g. Windows, Linux, AIX, etc.) store will potentially store their "cacerts" file (i.e. the file that contains all the trusted certificate authorities) in various places so I can't say exactly where you need to look to determine which specific authorities your JVM trusts, but you should be able to find that information in your JVM documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response Justin. I'm not from a Java background and I'm not sure how to check for the certs that the JVM installed on my Linux EC2 instances on AWS. Do you have any examples or links that can help me investigate. All my searchs have led me to articles suggesting that I will need certs on the Client. One from yourself here - https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled. Thanks for your time answering my question!

Comment: Are you having your certificates signed by a common authority (e.g. Comodo, Symantec, GeoTrust, etc.)? If so, that's likely to be trusted implicitly by the JVM you're using. To find out all the authorities which your JVM trusts you'll first have to figure out what JVM you're using and then consult the documentation for that JVM. I can't give you specific links on that but any decent search engine should be able to help.

Comment: The example you linked from the ActiveMQ Artemis GitHub is specifically using self-signed certificates. Are you using self-signed certs? If so, you'll need to import them on the client. That fact is outlined in my answer above.